# Playground Timeline Not Displaying View

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8.2

The timeline view is not working for me in Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.0. I am using the code below. Anyone have an idea why this isn't displaying anything in the Timeline? I am also wondering if it might be an Xcode issue.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320.0, height: 600.0))
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = contentView
```

Comment: Works for me ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOz_4Dc2CFVCx6l4HPK6XWiigt6XUKSvMzQ)).

Comment: And that's Xcode 8.2.1? If so, then I'm not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Yes, 8.2.1 (8C1002). No idea either.

Comment: i have same prob

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem might occur if there's running Simulator present. Also the good point is to restart XCode.